# Php insert array value into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

Please advice where i am doing wrong?

```
$db     = new mysqli("localhost","root","","saad");
$prep = array();
foreach($data_array as $k => $v ) {
    $prep[':'.$k] = $v;
}
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO records ( " . implode(', ',array_keys($data_array)) . ") VALUES (" . implode(', ',array_keys($prep)) . ")");
$res = $sth->execute($prep);
```

something i am not doing right

Comment: Probably you need quotes for each value,assuming they are not int

Comment: are you sure $data_array is not empty ?

Comment: What happens with the current code? Errors?

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving the query string into a separate variable:

```
$sql = "INSERT......";
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
```

and then try and see the $sql content (using `var_dump($sql)` for instance). This may set you on the right path.

Also, add this after `$sth->execute()`:

```
$error = $db->errorInfo();
echo $error[2];
```

This will show you the MySQL error message, if there is one. (Don't forget to remove all this debug output later though.)